# Limiting the second drop down list option using php and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am making a login system for a school for students and teachers.

When registering, the user needs to specify his/her user type: student or teacher.

If the user is a student, s/he then needs to specify their form group which is a combination of the year group (grade) and the base. For example, a student in Year 8 in base 5 would be in the form 8.5. The form for the teachers would be left 'null'.

The options for the year group and the base will be 2 separate drop down lists. As the number of the bases depends on the year group (Years 7-11 have 8 bases and Years 12 and 13 have 12 bases), I need to be able to limit the second drop down list for the base.

I am using php and MySQL using localhost via xampp and am very new to using both php and MySQL. If I need to learn another programming language I am open to do so.

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: I would use Javascript/jQuery with Ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this in multiple ways. I think if you are new and the options for your select are not too many this may be an easy approach.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#year").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "item1") {
            $("#base").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item2") {
            $("#base").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item3") {
            $("#base").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

So using jQuery you can read the option being selected on one dropdown and change the values of the other one.

As mention by other users this can also be archive by using Ajax and making a call to your database.